# Why is my RAID /dev/md1 showing up as /dev/md126? Is mdadm.conf being ignored?

Tags: mdadm

I created a RAID with:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md2 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2
```

`sudo mdadm --detail --scan` returns:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

Which I appended it to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, see below:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Mon, 29 Oct 2012 16:06:12 -0500
# by mkconf $Id$
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` returns:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdc2[1]
      208629632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      767868736 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`ls -la /dev | grep md` returns:

```
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9,   1 Oct 30 11:06 md1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9,   2 Oct 30 11:06 md2
```

So I think all is good and I reboot.

---

After the reboot, /dev/md1 is now **/dev/md126** and /dev/md2 is now **/dev/md127**?????

`sudo mdadm --detail --scan` returns:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/ion:1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md/ion:2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` returns:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[0]
      208629632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      767868736 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`ls -la /dev | grep md` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          80 Oct 30 11:18 md
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9, 126 Oct 30 11:18 md126
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9, 127 Oct 30 11:18 md127
```

---

All is not lost, I:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md126
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127
sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2
```

and verify everything:

`sudo mdadm --detail --scan` returns:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` returns:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdc2[1]
      208629632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      767868736 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`ls -la /dev | grep md` returns:

```
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9,   1 Oct 30 11:26 md1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9,   2 Oct 30 11:26 md2
```

So once again, I think all is good and I reboot.

---

Again, after the reboot, /dev/md1 is **/dev/md126** and /dev/md2 is **/dev/md127**?????

`sudo mdadm --detail --scan` returns:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/ion:1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md/ion:2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` returns:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[0]
      208629632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      767868736 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`ls -la /dev | grep md` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          80 Oct 30 11:42 md
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9, 126 Oct 30 11:42 md126
brw-rw----   1 root disk      9, 127 Oct 30 11:42 md127
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The only thing that's missing here is a problem. If `--name` is given in mdadm.conf, it assigns a random number, as you told it, that you prefer accessing the array through its name in `/dev/md/name`. It therefore keeps the lower numbers clear for arrays without names.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the answer here, [RAID starting at md127 instead of md0](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764861%29%3a).  In short, I chopped my /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf definitions from:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ion:1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=ion:2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

to:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=aa1f85b0:a2391657:cfd38029:772c560e
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=528e5385:e61eaa4c:1db2dba7:44b556fb
```

and ran:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I am **far** from an expert on this, but my understanding is this ...

The kernel assembled the arrays prior to the normal time to assemble the arrays occurs.  When the kernel assembles the arrays, it does not use mdadm.conf. Since the partitions had already been assembled by the kernel, the normal array assembly which uses mdadm.conf was skipped.

Calling `sudo update-initramfs -u` tells the kernel take a look at the system again to figure out how to start up.

I am sure someone with better knowledge will correct me / elaborate on this.

Use the following line to update the initrd for each respective kernel that exists on your system:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Comment: Yes, actually this would re-create the initrd for the kernel and include the configuration files relevant for the MD-RAID configuration. This means at the time the devices get created the kernel will know how to name them according to your setting. Good catch. +1 ... btw: noticed that this is also explained in the linked forum topic.

Comment: Hey, this answer solved a slow RAID initialization issue on my Arch Linux system.
It would take 5 seconds to get the RAID0 array up and running while booting. After changing mdadm.conf as described and running mkinitcpio, it takes negligible time!

Comment: Could not get Ubuntu 12.04 (Mint 13) to boot without this. I could not even get my root FS to mount from initramfs shell either. There were a bunch of dm-linear errors and 'bad superblock' errors trying to mount. I also made sure to rename my md0 device to 0, and md1 device to 1. I don't know if that was also needed.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The kernel does not assemble metadata1.2 arrays under any circumstances. But the only thing that's missing here is a problem. If `--name` is given in mdadm.conf, it assigns a random number, as you told it, that you prefer accessing the array through its name in `/dev/md/name`. It therefore keeps the lower numbers clear for arrays without names.

Comment: @Bachsau Is right people! All the other stories are non-sense.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

was all I needed to fix that. 
I did not edit anything in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

This solution solvd my problem:
http://aubreykloppers.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/mdadm-devmd127/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please include the relevant steps from the link in the answer.

Comment: A problem involves something being wrong. With `md126`, there is not. You could just have gone with it. "Problem" solved. Arrays assembled with a `--name` always get numbers 126 and above, as you told it, that you prefer accessing the array through its name in `/dev/md/name`. It therefore keeps the lower numbers clear for arrays without names.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate the issue in  the following manner:

When "Software Updater" asked if i wanted to update packages (including Ubuntu base" and kernel, i said:OK.
The newly installed kernel used the current kernel's/system's settings.
I then created the array.
Only the currently running kernel got updated with the new RAID settings.
Once i rebooted, the new kernel knew nothing about the raid, and gave it an md127 name!